# SELECT second highest timestamp and correlative columns

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

In a table with bags, where each bag have a location column and time column, I can get the most recent location with this query:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM bag_position b 
WHERE time = ( 
    SELECT MAX(c.time) 
    FROM bag_position c 
    WHERE c.bag_id = b.bag_id 
);
```

How can I get the second highest location? I tried with this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT b.*
from bag_position b
where time = ( select max(c.time) from bag_position c where c.time < (select max d.time from bag_position d) and c.bag_id = b.bag_id );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offset` and `limit` instead of `max()`:

```
select b.*
from bag_position b
where b.time = (select b2.time
                from bag_position b2
                where b2.bag_id = b.bag_id
                order by time desc
                limit 1 offset 1
               );
```

Comment: `offset 1 limit 1` should be `limit 1 offset 1` or `limit 1,1`

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . It is rather frustrating that different databases support `offset` . . . and then the syntax is different.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff.